# Append number to a list but skipping the first line: code not working

Tags: python

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this but it is driving me mad. I have the following code which is supposed to append numbers to two lists (first turning them into floats) but skipping the first line, as it contains strings. For some reason the "count" variable just remains at 1, rather than increasing:

```
gdp = []
unemp = []


data = open("C:/users/EuanRitchie/unempgdp.csv")
count = 1

for i in data:
    print count
    i = i.split(",")
    unemp.append(i[0])
    gdp.append(i[1])
    if count==1:
        count =+ 1
    elif count>1:
        unemp[i] = float(unemp[i])
        gdp[i] = float(gdp[i])
```

I know there are probably quicker ways to do this with a csv module but this is also practice. Clearly, I need it.

Comment: `'=+' !+ '+='`... `count =+ 1` is just `count = +1` or `count = 1`.

Comment: count+=1, not count=+1

Comment: It looks like you are reading a CSV file - if so, check out the built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore the first line just read it. Also, put your open in a `with` to make sure it closes properly. I don't think there is a need for a counter.

```
with open("C:/users/EuanRitchie/unempgdp.csv") as f:
    header = f.readline() #reads the first line
    for line in f:
        # Process the rest of the lines here
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, the += was a silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

To skip the first item of an iterable convert it to an iterator and iterate once:

```
it = iter(data)
next(it, None) # if present, skip first item
```

Then use you data

```
for item in it:
    # whatever
```

Alternatively you can use `enumerate` to keep track of `count` for you:

```
for count, item in enumerate(data):
    if count == 0:
        continue # skip first line
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing count. The correct syntax is:
`count += 1` 
and not `count =+ 1` (which will always keep count's value equal to 1)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo:

```
count =+ 1
```

but should be

```
count += 1
```